# In my Angular form, I added keycode event with F2. Why is it not working on certein situations?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, events, keycode

What I did: I created angular html page with a form. The form includes some input data with autofocus.
I added an event "F2" key that fires console message.

My goal: Make it work with all states.

The problem: This event works only when I press on the input field area and then F12 - but it doesn't work when I am not in focus with the input area.

html code:

```
<body>
<div class="container">
<h1 class="header"> מחשבון עצים אמריקאים</h1>
<form #myform="ngForm" (keydown)="keyDownFunction($event)">
    <div>
        <label for="mbf" class="label">בורד פיט:</label>
        <!--input with minus not allowed -->
        <input type="number" min="0" name="mbf" [(ngModel)]="mbfValue" autofocus required #mbf="ngModel" onkeypress="return event.charCode != 45">
        <span class="error-message" *ngIf="mbf.dirty && mbf.invalid">לא הוזן מספר</span>            
        <label for="rowOne">שורה:</label>
        <input type="number" min="0" name="rowOne" [(ngModel)]="rowOneValue" autofocus required #rowOne="ngModel" onkeypress="return event.charCode != 45" placeholder="1">
        <span class="error-message" *ngIf="mbf.dirty && mbf.invalid">לא הוזן מספר</span>            
    </div>
    <div class="slider">
        <mat-slide-toggle [formControl]="autoRenew" (change)="onChange()">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;מכפיל {{addonPrint}}</mat-slide-toggle>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p class="cbm">תוצאה בקו"ב:</p>
        <p class="result">{{cbm}}</p>
    </div>

</form>  
</div>
```

Typescript code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { MathService } from 'src/app/services/math.service';


@Component({
    selector: 'app-mbf-hardwood-calc',
    templateUrl: './mbf-hardwood-calc.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./mbf-hardwood-calc.component.css']
})
export class MbfHardwoodCalcComponent implements OnInit {
    mbfValue: number;
    rowOneValue: number;
    cbm: string;
    twoFiveFourAddon = false;
    autoRenew = new FormControl();
    addonPrint = 236;


constructor(private mathService: MathService) { }

ngOnInit() {
}
// toggles between 236 and 254 modes
onChange() {
    this.autoRenew.value ? this.addonPrint = 254 : this.addonPrint = 236; // print next to switch sign
    if (!isNaN(this.mbfValue)) { this.cbm = this.mathService.mbf2cbm(this.mbfValue, this.autoRenew.value).toFixed(3); }


}
// enter key pressed event catcher
keyDownFunction(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 113) {
        console.log('F2 pressed');
    } else if (event.keyCode === 13 && !isNaN(this.mbfValue)) {
        this.cbm = this.mathService.mbf2cbm(this.mbfValue, this.autoRenew.value).toFixed(3);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

**Reason of not working :-**

You have put you key down event only on form so that it will trigger only if you press key in you form.

**Solution:-**

Use   - *@HostListner* like follow in your typescript class:

```
  @HostListener('document:keypress', ['$event'])
  handleKeyboardEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) { 
    this.key = event.key;
    // Here you will get key
    this.keyDownFunction(event)        // Now you can call you function 
  }
```

I hope this will help

Answer (score 1):

Import HostListener into your ts file

`import { HostListener } from '@angular/core';`

Use keydown instead of keypress

```
@HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event'])
  handleKeyboardEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    if(event.key === 'F2'){
      console.log('F2 pressed');
      // Call Function
    } else if (event.key === 'Enter' && !isNaN(this.mbfValue)){
      this.cbm = this.mathService.mbf2cbm(this.mbfValue, this.autoRenew.value).toFixed(3);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow guys that worked perfectly. And thank you for suggesting me using keydown instead of keypress - Doing so it's important to remove the (keydown)="handleKeyboardEvent($event)" from the html code otherwise it will print double messages to the console.

Thank you very much!